# What does THO, as in "USD THO", stand for in export statistics?

Tags: inflation, currency, exchange-rates, definition, value

I've noticed that some online sources use "USD THO" as a unit to express rates of transfer of value. Specifically, I saw it in measuring Chinese exports to Russia in this video at 21:20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ce5TR-qWCk4&t=1280s and, when I tried to look it up to find out what it meant, I saw that it is used by tradingeconomics.com ( https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/imports-of-consumption-of-carbon-steel-produc https://tradingeconomics.com/ecuador/changes-in-inventories ), iqstock.news ( https://www.iqstock.news/n/china-exports-crude-petroleum-3043534/ ), and a couple of South Asian economics papers ( http://doi.org/10.47205/plhr.2020(4-II)2.2 and https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3697430 (ISBN: 788 193 050774) ). Obviously, "USD" stands for "United States Dollar"; however, it is unusually difficult to find a meaning of "THO" which is obviously appropriate here. The best I've found are the "stock ticker" of **Thor Industries** at the New York Stock Exchange (NYSE: THO), **Tahoe Resources inc.** (which is invariably listed along with the words "Toronto Stock Exchange" when associated with "THO"), "**Thai Offshore Baht**" (Unless it's THai Offshore baht, don't ask me in what language that spells "THO", but apparently it does, as opposed to "THB" which is just Thai Baht. The currency apparently had very different "offshore" and "onshore" exchange rates from 2006 to 2008.), and some kind of cryptocurrency called "**Thorus**" (which has THO and sTHO tokens). None of these makes much sense to me. There's also something called a "**Traditional Hand-Off**", which is listed under "Technology, IT etc." by http://acronymsandslang.com/meaning-of/technology-IT/THO.html , though I can't figure out what it means, along with **many other unpromising meanings** I've found on that and similar sites.

Comment: Thousands seems likely

Comment: That's so obvious! I can't believe I didn't think of it.
There's probably an implied "per year" in at least some of those sources, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I found from another website that in Trading Economics parlance, this means thousands of US dollars (written as "USD THO").